# Rowwise in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

This is the question I asked before, But I explained it in the wrong way, So I am going to open a new question again.Appreciate your help and time !

Data Input:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'variable':["A","A","B","B","C","D","E","E","E","F","F","G"],'weight':[2,2,0,0,1,3,3,1,5,0,0,4]})
df
Out[447]: 
   variable  weight
0         A       2
1         A       2
2         B       0
3         B       0
4         C       1
5         D       3
6         E       3
7         E       1# If value more than 2 , out put should be 0
8         E       5
9         F       0
10        F       0
11        G       4
```

Expected Output :

```
df
Out[449]: 
   variable  weight    NEW
0         A       2      1
1         A       2      1
2         B       0      1
3         B       0      1
4         C       1      1
5         D       3  ERROR
6         E       3  ERROR
7         E       1      1
8         E       5      1
9         F       0      1
10        F       0      1
11        G       4  ERROR
```

My approach as of now (ugly..):

```
l1=[]
for i in df.variable.unique():
    temp=df.loc[df.variable==i]
    l2 = []
    for j in range(len(temp)):
        print(i,j)

        if temp.iloc[j,1]<=2 :
            l2.append(1)
        elif temp.iloc[j,1]>2 and j==0:
            l2.append('ERROR')
        elif temp.iloc[j,1]>2 and j > 0 :
            if l2[j - 1] == 1:
                l2.append(1)
            else:
                l2.append(0)
        print(l2)
    l1.extend(l2)
df['NEW']=l1
```

---

My question here:

*1st*. If I want to use `groupby` , how can I make per-calculated result involved in the future calculation , in order to get the `NEW` column here.

*2nd*. Is there any `pandas` function like [`.Last.value`](http://rfunction.com/archives/1561) in `R` ?

---

I will explain the condition here :

1.If the value of weight less than 2 always should be 1

2.If the first value of weight  higher than 2 it should be return `ERROR`

3.If the previous one getting 'ERROR' and weight value current row is more than 2 it will return 0

And kindly change The Input to :

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'variable':["A","A","B","B","C","D","E","E","E","F","F","G"],'weight':[2,2,0,0,1,3,3,9,5,0,0,4]})
```

Comment: would you mind explaining the logic behind "ERROR" values?

Comment: @MaxU The first value in each group will be either `ERROR` or `1`

Comment: I still don't understand when it should be `ERROR`, when `1` and when `0`...

Comment: @MaxU if the value no less than 2 always should be 1 and , if the first value higher than 2 it should be return ''ERROR'', the condition to get the 0 : if the previous one getting 'ERROR' and weight is of current is more than 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
n = 2  # `Error` weight filter.
# Get boolean index of whether weight of first item in group is greater than `n`.
mask = df.loc[[idx[0] for idx in df.groupby('variable')['weight'].groups.values()], 'weight'].gt(n)
df = df.assign(New=1)
df.loc[mask[mask].index, 'New'] = 'ERROR'
>>> df
   variable  weight    New
0         A       2      1
1         A       2      1
2         B       0      1
3         B       0      1
4         C       1      1
5         D       3  ERROR
6         E       3  ERROR
7         E       1      1
8         E       5      1
9         F       0      1
10        F       0      1
11        G       4  ERROR
```

Comment: How about , change input to `df=pd.DataFrame({'variable':["A","A","B","B","C","D","E","E","E","F","F","G"],'weight':[2,2,0,0,1,3,3,9,5,0,0,4]})`

Comment: @Wen This does not change the results.  The revised df per you comment above changes the second weight of `E` from `1` to `9` and hence has no impact (as confirmed by running the code).

Comment: To confirm, it only flags `ERROR` when the _first_ weight in a given variable group exceeds the target `n` (e.g. 3).

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I understood the condition correctly from your loop, but this looks like it

```
df['New'] = np.where((df['weight'] > 2) & (df['variable'] != df['variable'].shift(1)), 'ERROR', 1)

    variable    weight  New
0   A           2       1
1   A           2       1
2   B           0       1
3   B           0       1
4   C           1       1
5   D           3       ERROR
6   E           3       ERROR
7   E           1       1
8   E           5       1
9   F           0       1
10  F           0       1
11  G           4       ERROR
```

Comment: Oh great:) Just that you might want to ensure that the column variable is sorted for this to work.

Comment: Sorry ,If i change the input of it, and the output get different from yours and my approach

Comment: Wen, sorry I am seeing this very late. Out of curiosity sake, what's the expected output with the revised df?

Comment: Only Group(E) changed `6         E       3  ERROR
7         E       9      0
8         E       5      0`

Comment: I am confused now as the other solution is also giving the same output on the new dataframe. Anyway...

Comment: Seems like , I can only use the for loop to achieve this , anyway, thank for your time ~ really appreciate ! ~ (PS,he asked me this question ..)

Comment: No problems, I was a little confused to just clarified:)